# using PHP CURLFile to upload Dropbox

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, php-curl

I'm trying to use PHP new CURLFile to upload a file to Dropbox API but I keep getting

> path/not_found/..

I'm using PHP > 7

and the code snippet is as follows:-

```
.....
    $curl_opts = [CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // exclude header from output
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // but return!
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false];
    $curl_opts[ CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER ] =  [
            "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $this->getToken(),
            "Content-Type" => "application/octet-stream",
            "Dropbox-API-Arg" => json_encode($params)
          ];
    $curl_opts[ CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ] = ['file' => new CURLFile($_FILES['tmp_name'], null, $_FILES['name']) ];
    $curl_opts[ CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST ] = 'POST';
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_opts);
    ...
```

How do I use CURLFile to send to DropBox files/upload endpoint?

the data being sent is as follows:-

> Array ( [42] => [19913] => 1 [64] => [10036] => POST [10015] => Array
>   ( [0] => CURLFile Object ( [name] => /tmp/phpTra0RG [mime] =>
>   application/octet-stream [postname] => BAR-TENDER-BIO-FORM.docx ) )
>   [10023] => Array ( [0] => Content-Type: application/octet-stream [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102697/dropbox-api-application-octet-stream-header)
>   => Authorization: Bearer *REDACTED* ,[2]
>   => Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/GCC2020/2019-06-17/zone-8/azerbaijan/fulle/BAR-TENDER-BIO-FORM.docx","mode":"overwrite","autorename":false,"mute":true,"strict_conflict":false}
>   ) )

The path token and file all seem legit. Can CURLFile handle `tmp_name` file paths from `$_FILES` ??

UPDATE

it seems my error may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102697/dropbox-api-application-octet-stream-header) PHP Curls seems to want to add the boundary markings due to me sending an array. `$curl_opts[ CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ] = ['file' => new CURLFile($_FILES['tmp_name'], null, $_FILES['name']) ];`

Honestly I'm not sure how to send a new CURLFile() without using '@' as based on the PHP i'm using it has been removed.....

Comment: @Kendall your included code seems to be missing some potentially relevant pieces, such as the `$params`, as well as the API endpoint you're trying to use. I recommend updating your question to include those for context.

Comment: @Greg can't put too much of the code. But based on the output from the curlopts all seems to be correct

Comment: @Kendall The API endpoint you're calling is going to be relevant, and itself isn't sensitive, so I suggest adding that to make it easier to help. You mentioned uploading files to the Dropbox API, for instance, which would imply the use of the [/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) endpoint, but per the docs that one doesn't have a `path/not_found` error, so there seems to be some disconnect somewhere.

Comment: @Greg you are correct about the endpoint. I've narrowed down the error but not sure what the solution is.....